# SFML Only Lists Invalid VideoModes in Debug Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

I have this weird problem where SFML's `sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes()` method, which is supposed to only return valid video modes, actually only returns invalid video modes.

When I change my launch configuration to Release it works fine.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argCount, char** argVector) {
    std::vector<sf::VideoMode> videoModes;
    videoModes = sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes();
    sf::VideoMode videoMode;

for(unsigned i = 0; i < videoModes.size(); i++) {
    if(videoModes[i].isValid()) 
        std::cout << "Vanlid VideoMode: " << i << " - " << videoModes[i].width << "x" << videoModes[i].height << " b" << videoModes[i].bitsPerPixel << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Invalid VideoMode: " << i << " - " << videoModes[i].width << "x" << videoModes[i].height << " b" << videoModes[i].bitsPerPixel << std::endl;
}
    char input[1];
    std::cin >> input;
    return 0;
}
```

Console Output: 

Invalid VideoMode: 0 - 3131961357x3131961357 b3131961357

Invalid VideoMode: 1 - 3131961357x3131961357 b3131961357

Invalid VideoMode: 2 - 3131961357x3131961357 b3131961357

Invalid VideoMode: 3 - 3131961357x3131961357 b3131961357

Comment: The code itself is fine, for me it outputs 18 valid video modes. What graphics card do you have? Have you got the latest drivers for it?

Comment: Irrelevant, it works in release mode.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's completely irrelevant when it works in both modes for me using the same version of Visual Studio.

Comment: It seems to be working if I use the debug libraries.

Comment: I assume by debug libraries you are referring to compile in debug using the debug SFML libraries rather than the release ones?

Comment: If I compile in debug mode, using the debug libraries, it works. If I debug in release mode, using the regular libraries, it works. Wonder why that'd make a difference. The libraries aren't built for VC++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the same as on this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17777615/2558778

You have to use the debug libraries in debug mode, and the release ones in release mode. Mixing them up can result in crashes.